# can we have some Listener for markers on Google map?

Tags: dictionary, google-maps-markers

i have some markers on Google map and i want to add Listener function (click on markers) for each markers that not same 
can i do that ? or we should have one listener for click ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a single marker click listener on a GoogleMap. The listener will get the marker as argument, so you can know which one was clicked. You can for example create a HashMap with Markers as keys and the associated data object as values so you can find out which object of your model has been selected.